# 'New Contributor' under my profile on the question which I asked using other profile but merged later

Tags: bug, merge-accounts, new-contributor-indicator

I asked a question on my other profile but later, I merged that profile with my original profile. I visited that question after merging profile and saw that there is `New Contributor` written under my profile which doesn't show up on other questions and answers. The link to that question is **[Get AM or PM using 'time'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342058/get-am-or-pm-using-time)**

[image: nc]

And example links to other question on which that text doesn't show:

- [How to convert png image to boundries ( for circle ) [pygame]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673808/how-to-convert-png-image-to-boundries-for-circle-pygame)
- [Make opencv frame non resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684678/make-opencv-frame-non-resizable)

Comment: I'd wait at least 24 hours for this; it smells like caching.

Comment: I believe that the "New Contributor" flag is set on the post at the time of creation, and never cleared. It simply stops displaying the banner once the post is 7 days old. So a merge would never clear it. Though I suppose we could do that calculation as part of the merge process and clear the flag from all posts if it succeeds...

Comment: **The indicator is removed**